# How to check more than one unrelated conditions in SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have following query:

```
SQL> SELECT DISTINCT INSTRUCTORADDRESSMODPER.instructor_id, Instructor.instructor_name, InstructorRank.salary, Student.specification_id
  2  FROM INSTRUCTORADDRESSMODPER
  3  JOIN Student ON INSTRUCTORADDRESSMODPER.student_id = Student.student_id
  4  JOIN Instructor ON INSTRUCTORADDRESSMODPER.instructor_id = Instructor.instructor_id
  5  JOIN InstructorRank ON Instructor.instructor_rank = InstructorRank.instructor_rank
  6  ORDER BY specification_id;
```

which has yielded following result:
[image]

I was trying to get result which shows same column values for instructors with same salary and same specification as highlighted in the figure. Now these two conditions require completely different checks and I don't even know how to get started.

Comment: Use WHERE clause.

Comment: how can I compare if two salaries are equal without inserting direct values?

Comment: Specify criteria to find the rows and compare to the salaries of the rows found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need something like this ?

```sql
SELECT instructor_id, instructor_name, instructor_name, specification_id
FROM (
SELECT DISTINCT INSTRUCTORADDRESSMODPER.instructor_id, Instructor.instructor_name, InstructorRank.instructor_name, Student.specification_id
, COUNT(distinct INSTRUCTORADDRESSMODPER.instructor_id)over(partition by InstructorRank.salary, Student.specification_id) cnt
  FROM INSTRUCTORADDRESSMODPER
  JOIN Student ON INSTRUCTORADDRESSMODPER.student_id = Student.student_id
  JOIN Instructor ON INSTRUCTORADDRESSMODPER.instructor_id = Instructor.instructor_id
  JOIN InstructorRank ON Instructor.instructor_rank = InstructorRank.instructor_rank
  ORDER BY specification_id
  )
WHERE cnt > 1
;
```

Comment: thanks man exactly what I was looking for, I tested it with other data too.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the window function `count` as follows:

```
Select * from 
(SELECT DISTINCT INSTRUCTORADDRESSMODPER.instructor_id, Instructor.instructor_name, InstructorRank.salary, Student.specification_id,
          Count(1) over (partition by InstructorRank.salary, Student.specification_id) as cnt
     FROM INSTRUCTORADDRESSMODPER
     JOIN Student ON INSTRUCTORADDRESSMODPER.student_id = Student.student_id
     JOIN Instructor ON INSTRUCTORADDRESSMODPER.instructor_id = Instructor.instructor_id
     JOIN InstructorRank ON Instructor.instructor_rank = InstructorRank.instructor_rank)
Where cnt > 1
ORDER BY specification_id;
```

Comment: says ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected. However thank you for pointing me to the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

```
SQL> SELECT DISTINCT INSTRUCTORADDRESSMODPER.instructor_id, 
Instructor.instructor_name,InstructorRank.salary, Student.specification_id
FROM INSTRUCTORADDRESSMODPER
WHERE 1=1
AND INSTRUCTORADDRESSMODPER.student_id = Student.student_id
AND  INSTRUCTORADDRESSMODPER.instructor_id = Instructor.instructor_id
AND  Instructor.instructor_rank = InstructorRank.instructor_rank
AND ORDER BY specification_id
AND ...;
```

With the above use, desired conditions can be added.